# Log4j SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy + DefaultRolloverStrategy not working

Tags: log4j

I am trying to edit a log4j to log 1000 rotations of 25MB log files.

This is the current config:

```
<Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="LogFile" filename="${log-path}/${log-file-name}" append="true" filePattern="${log-path}/${log-file-name}.%i">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %-32c{1} - %m%n"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1000"/>
</Appenders>
```

I've searched for a solution but unfortunatly have not found anything usefull in my situation.